# Por qual motivo as divs movem de lugar após inserir um conteúdo?

Tags: html, css

Se eu tirar as tags  ele fica alinhado certinho, porem quando insiro a imagem ou, por exemplo, h1 ele já desce novamente, se inserir em todos ele volta ao normal, mas porque isto ocorre?

```css
body {
  background-color: #DDDDDD
}
#container1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
#ativos {
  width: 180px;
  height: 190px;
  background-color: #1461c4;
}
#status {
  width: 244px;
  height: 190px;
  background-color: #DE962F;
}
#instalados {
  width: 216px;
  height: 190px;
  background-color: #DE962F;
}
#recebimentos {
  width: 613px;
  height: 190px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="ativos" class="box">
    <img src="icones/ativos.png">
    <!--<H5>CLIENTES ATIVOS</H5>-->
  </div>
  <div id="status" class="box">
    <!--<H5>STATUS CLIENTES</H5>-->
  </div>
  <div id="instalados" class="box">
    <img src="icones/ion.png">
    <!--<h5>CLIENTES INSTALADOS</h5>-->
  </div>
  <div id="recebimentos" class="box">
    <img src="">
    <!--<h5>RECEBIMENTOS LOCAL MÊS</h5>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vitor, a sua pergunta está muito confusa. Dê uma lida aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask vai ajuda-lo na próxima vez.

Answer (score 2):

É só colocar:

`vertical-align: top` ou `overflow: hidden`.

Na classe `box`.

Usando o `vertical-align: top`, os elementos ficarão no topo independente do seu conteúdo que podem alterar o elemento pai devido suas propriedades nativas, como o `margin` e o `padding`.

Usando o `overflow: hidden` realizará o mesmo que o `vertical-align`, mas pode te prejudicar em outros coisas caso você defina uma largura ou altura fixa. O `overflow: hidden` não permite que o elemento pai seja modificado por propriedades dos elementos filhos.

---

```css
body {
  background-color: #DDDDDD
}
#container1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#ativos {
  width: 180px;
  height: 190px;
  background-color: #1461c4;
}
#status {
  width: 244px;
  height: 190px;
  background-color: #DE962F;
}
#instalados {
  width: 216px;
  height: 190px;
  background-color: #DE962F;
}
#recebimentos {
  width: 613px;
  height: 190px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
  <div id="ativos" class="box">
    <img src="icones/ativos.png">
    <!--<H5>CLIENTES ATIVOS</H5>-->
  </div>
  <div id="status" class="box">
    <!--<H5>STATUS CLIENTES</H5>-->
  </div>
  <div id="instalados" class="box">
    <img src="icones/ion.png">
    <!--<h5>CLIENTES INSTALADOS</h5>-->
  </div>
  <div id="recebimentos" class="box">
    <img src="">
    <!--<h5>RECEBIMENTOS LOCAL MÊS</h5>-->
  </div>
</div>
```